# Ffmpeg in Lambda function along with API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda, ffmpeg

My question is I designed a Lambda function that perfectly works in Test option but when I try to invoke the same function via API Gateway Ffmpeg didn't work properly it delivers empty file like an audio file with 0bytes.

My code is using python
HTTP API

My code concept is to build an audio converter api using ffmpeg. Can anyone help me out this.

Comment: When using the 'Test' function in AWS Lambda, you would have provided information in a **Test Event**. This information is passed to the Lambda function via the `event` parameter. Presumably, your function would have extracted information from the `event` parameter and used it somehow (eg retrieving an object from Amazon S3). When invoking the Lambda function via API Gateway, the contents of the `event` would have been populated by API Gateway. A good first step to debug your situation is to have your Lambda function **print the `event`** variable. You could then examine what it contains.

Comment: Ok but event contains the URL that I pass

Comment: API Gateway will pass the URL.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Actually the event has correct url and ffmpeg creates a fil with no data